# How can I convert Youtube blob:videourl to actual source URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, revokeobjecturl

While watching any Youtube video, if the video element is inspected (in Chrome devtools) then the `src` attribute of the video tag shows `blob:https://youtube.com/somerandomhash` instead of the actual source url.

Can I somehow retrieve the actual source url of the video in Javascript (or jQuery) such that it can be played in an isolated tab (That I suppose is the default behavior of HTML5 video players) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just embed the video to the isolated tab?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/773998

Comment: @ChristosLytras - My use-case requires the exact video source URL so that it can be played in a new tab with the default HTML5 player (and not with the Youtube player wrapper).

StevenPenny - Thank you for your help. It certainly seems like a pretty tough job but I think your solution will work.